# Why does my Angular directive behave like this?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to implement a directive that changes some HTML colors in a view when a certain `{{valueFromServer}}` changes. Currently, I've tried the following:

View:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up voteColorer" ng-click="upvote(post)" votes="{{valueFromServer}}"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down voteColorer" ng-click="downvote(post)" votes="{{valueFromServer}}"></span>
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('voteColorer', function () {
    return {
    restrict : 'C',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.bind("click" , function(e){

                 attrs.$observe('votes', function() {
                    console.log(elem); // for testing purposes
                    // would like to do color change operations here
                 });                 
            });     
        }
    }
});
```

When I click either of the glyphicon spans and `valueFromServer` changes I'd **expect** the directive to log into the console the span element I just clicked.

What it **actually** does is it first logs the span I click. On my second click it logs the span I clicked AND the span I clicked before that. On my third click it logs the span I just clicked, the span I clicked before that and the span I clicked before that etc. So on e.g. my fifth click the directive prints five console.log elements.

Why does it do this and how do I get rid of this behavior?

Comment: You're not logging the value of the attribute on click. You add an observer to the attribute changes each time you click. Just pur the attrs.$observe() call directly in the link function. That said, you're reinventing the wheel. Just use ng-class.

Comment: @JBNizet If I put the attrs.$observe() call directly in the link function, clicking either span console.logs both the clicked span and the span I did not click. Can you tell me why? Also, if I go with your suggestion of using ng-class instead how should I detect the change in the `valueFromServer`?

Comment: Well, the valueFromServer is observed in both spans, and it changes in both spans, so it's logged in both spans. ng-class observes the value for you. Have you read the documentation? You've not said exactly what you wanted to achieve, but let's say for example you want the class foo to be added when the value is >= 0, and the class bar when the value is < 0, you would just use `ng-class="{foo: valueFromServer >= 0, bar: valueFromServer < 0}"`.

Comment: @JBNizet Okay, thanks. I have, yes. What I'm trying to achieve is to add a class to the span the user clicked and simultaneously remove a class from the span the user did not click. And this all should happen **only** if the clicking changes `valueFromServer`, which does not always happen.

Comment: Then when a span is clicked and changes the value, store its id/name/whatever ('up' or 'down', for example) in the model, and use `ng-class="{colored: lastClickWithChange === 'up'}` and `ng-class="{colored: lastClickWithChange === 'down'}`

Comment: @JBNizet Alright, thank you!